# FQL friends who have visited a place

Tags: facebook, facebook-fql

I'm trying to find a way to find all my Facebook friends who have been in a given place.

For instance if I go here

https://www.facebook.com/pages/Fano/104100952959686

I see 198 friends who have been in Fano. I wonder which is the FQL query to get the same results...I'm trying to select on FQL tables checkin, location_post both filtering by coordinates (using distance) or page_id but I did not find any way to get the same data...

Any help!?